# Can LinearOptimization (ex. LinearProgramming) support other methods (Ellipsoid method)?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, code-request, implementation-details

Can [LinearOptimization (ex. LinearProgramming)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming.html) support methods other than "InteriorPoint", "Simplex", "RevisedSimplex"?

Specifically, I need the [Ellipsoid Method](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47837-ellipsoid-method). Are there implementations for Mathematica already available somewhere or do I need to implement it myself from scratch?

Comment: `LinearProgramming[Range[200], 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1., Band[{1, 2}] -> 2.}, {100, 200}], 
 Range[100], Method -> "Ellipsoid"]` produces a warning  "LinearProgramming::lpmethod: Ellipsoid is not a valid method for linear programming."

Comment: `BoundingRegion` does have a `"MinEllipsoid"` argument, so you could use that to construct the algorithm yourself.

Comment: The webpage you provided is for somebody's Masters thesis, and is apparently not a widely used algorithm. I haven't looked at the thesis, but I suspect that algorithm can be implemented using one of the functions at  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ConvexOptimization.html

Comment: At the very least, the iterative implementation is [straightforward](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262456/49840).