# Code review of my animation of Ellipsoid method

Tags: mathematical-optimization, animation, code-review

Feel free to suggest improvements ([code-review](/questions/tagged/code-review)) to my two functions (calculation and animation).

They were made to visualize the workings of the Ellipsoid method in two dimensions.

For example, see the gif below.

[image]

The example above was created as

```
A = {{-1, -1}, {3, 0}, {-2, 2}};
b = {-2, 4, 3};
r = 7;
plotRange = 10;
ex1 = ell2d[A, b, r];
imgs1 = ell2dPlot[ex1, plotRange];
Animate[imgs1[[t]], {t, 1, Length[imgs1], 1}, AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> 1]
Export["ex1.gif", imgs1, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

Where the calculating part returns a list `ll` of form {iteration, hyperplane index, ellipsoid, ellipsoid center} (except for the last element of the list, which contains other relevant information), following [the iterative pseudocode](https://eclass.upatras.gr/modules/document/file.php/EE896/course_material/EllipsoidMethod-1.pdf) for the basic ellipsoid method,

```
ell2d[A_, b_, r_, kmax_: 100, n_: 2] := 
  Module[{ll, Bk, xk, \[Tau], \[Sigma], \[Delta], x, Axb, AxbList, Bkk, xkk},
   Bk = r^2*IdentityMatrix[n];
   xk = {{0, 0}};
   \[Tau] = 1/(n + 1);
   \[Sigma] = 2/(n + 1);
   \[Delta] = n^2/(n^2 - 1);
   x = {x1, x2};
   Axb = Inner[LessEqual, A.x, b, And] && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0;
   AxbList = Inner[LessEqual, A.x, b, List];
   ll = {};
   Do[
    If[k == kmax, Print["Max k=", k, " reached."]];
    If[Axb /. {x1 -> xk[[1]][[1]], x2 -> xk[[1]][[2]]},
     Print["Point ", xk[[1]] // N, " is in region. (" , k, " iter.)"];
     Break[];
     ];
    i = FirstPosition[AxbList /. {x1 -> xk[[1]][[1]], x2 -> xk[[1]][[2]]}, False];
    aj = A[[i]] // Transpose;
    AppendTo[ll, {k, i, Bk, xk}];
    Bkk = \[Delta] (Bk - \[Sigma] ((Bk.aj.Transpose[Bk.aj])/(Transpose[aj].Bk.aj)[[1]][[1]]));
    xkk = Transpose[xk] - \[Tau] ((Bk.aj)/(Sqrt[Transpose[aj].Bk.aj])[[1]][[1]]);
    Bk = N[Bkk];
    xk = N[Transpose[xkk]];
    , {k, 0, kmax}];
   AppendTo[ll, {A.x, Axb, Bk, xk}];
   ll];
```

Where the animating part returns a list of plots, adding 3 per iteration,

```
ell2dPlot[ll_, plotRange_, pltX_: 0, pltY_: 0] := 
  Module[{imgs, Ax, Axb, L, ells, i, Bk, xk, x, e, h, ell},
   L = Length[ll];
   Ax = ll[[L]][[1]];
   Axb = ll[[L]][[2]];
   imgs = {};
   ells = {};
   Do[
    i = ll[[k]][[2]];
    Bk = ll[[k]][[3]];
    xk = ll[[k]][[4]];
    x = {{x1, x2}} - xk;
    e = (x.Inverse[Bk].Transpose[x])[[1]][[1]] <= 1;
    AppendTo[ells,
     RegionPlot[
      e, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2, 
       pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange},
      PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.00]},
      BoundaryStyle -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2]
      ]];
    AppendTo[imgs,
     Show[
      ells,
      RegionPlot[{Axb}, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2,
         pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}],
      RegionPlot[
       e, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2, 
        pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange},
       PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.01]},
       BoundaryStyle -> Black
       ],
      ListPlot[{xk},
       PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.1]}]
      ]
     ];
    h = (Ax)[[i]][[
       1]] <= (((Ax)[[i]]) /. {x1 -> xk[[1]][[1]], 
          x2 -> xk[[1]][[2]]})[[1]];
    ell = {
      RegionPlot[
       e, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2, 
        pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange},
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.01]
       ],
      RegionPlot[
       e && h, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2, 
        pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}],
      ListPlot[{xk},
       PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.1]}
       ]
      };
    i = ll[[k + 1]][[2]];
    Bk = ll[[k + 1]][[3]];
    xk = ll[[k + 1]][[4]];
    x = {{x1, x2}} - xk;
    e = (x.Inverse[Bk].Transpose[x])[[1]][[1]] <= 1;
    AppendTo[imgs, Show[
      ells,
      RegionPlot[{Axb}, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2,
         pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}],
      ell]];
    AppendTo[imgs,
     Show[
      ells,
      RegionPlot[{Axb}, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2,
         pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}],
      ell,
      RegionPlot[
       e, {x1, pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange}, {x2, 
        pltX - plotRange, pltY + plotRange},
       PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.01]},
       BoundaryStyle -> Black
       ],
      ListPlot[{xk}, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.1]}]]
     ];
    , {k, 1, Length[ll] - 1}];
   imgs];
```

Comment: Don't use AppendTo, use Reap and Sow

Comment: Please identify any specific problem in your code. As it stands, your question lacks focus and may even lead to opinion-based answers (e.g. what is "better" here?).

Comment: @MarcoB I'm guessing the "problem" (in a fully functioning code, as the tag describes) would be readability (tag describes "improvement of style") and more appropriate function alternatives (e.g. what previous comment suggested).